# Difference between RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent Vs EnvironmentChangeEvent

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

As per the class level comment

1. **org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentChangeEvent**

> Event published to signal a change in the {@link Environment}.

This is too generic and I do not know what are all included when we say change in the Environment.

2. **org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent**

> Sadly this class does not have a class comment.

My understanding is that RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent handles changes in property values in config-server but looks like it does not instead such event is available through EnvironmentChangeEvent.

I did hit /refresh endpoint but it does not call my listener class with RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event. Instead EnvironmentChangeEvent got a call for /refresh

Comment: can you share implementation of your listener class?

Answer (score 2):

**EnvironmentChangeEvent** is fired when there's a change in Environment. In terms of Spring Cloud Config it means it's triggered when **/env** actuator endpoint is called.

**RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent** is fired when refresh of @RefreshScope beans has been initiated, e.g. **/refresh** actuator endpoint is called.

You can by registering ApplicationListener like that:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

@EventListener(RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent.class)
public void onRefresh(RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {
    // Your code goes here...
  }
}
```